# Remote desktop for Windows 10 IoT

Tags: gratis, remote-desktop, windows-10, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 with Windows 10 IoT and I can deploy and debug my applications. However, I only have 1 screen, so if I want to see the UI displayed by Raspberry Pi, I need to disconnect the cable of my monitor, connect it to the Raspberry and back again.

I am looking for a tool which

- runs on [Windows 10 IoT](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/Downloads.htm) (ARM), particularly for Raspberry Pi 2 (server side)
- forwards the screen to a Windows 10 (x86, Desktop) client
- frame rate should be at least 5 per second
- is free, Open Source preferred

The tool needn't

- forward mouse or keyboard events as I have attached a keyboard

Comment: Have you considered using a hdmi splitter? Then you can duplicate the screen output from the Raspberry pi.

Comment: Another option could possibly be to use team viewer or remote desktop. Have you tried that?

Comment: @holroy: yes, I thought about something similar, a KVM switch. If it's possible in software, I'd prefer not to buy additional hardware. My screen is VGA Sub-D by the way.

Comment: @holroy: I couldn't connect to the Raspberry via Remote Desktop. Perhaps it's just turned off by default (like in other Windows editions) but since W10 IoT does not have a Desktop, I don't know how to turn it on.

Comment: you say can deploy your application, I would suggest finding out how to enable remote desktop via a temporary modification to your application.

Answer (score 1):

There is now an option to do this through [Remote Display Experience](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/RemoteDisplay.htm).